# Android services , bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have some question regaring the `service framework` for android phones. As this post is written I do create a  `bluetoothserversocket` inside a `thread`. This thread is called from an `Activity`. But when the activity shuts down, the socket also closes, of course. My problem is that when the application is restarted the android system chooses a random channel for this `bluetoothserversocket`. I was wondering if I could create a service to create this `serversocket` and just call I from the `Activity`, will the serversocket close, when the application closes? I've looked at some examples regarding this, and there is an `implemeted` method called

```
 @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      //code to execute when the service is shutting down
   }
```

Will this method be called when the application closes? In other words, I need a service which runs all the time, when the phone is turned on.